# Delete rows in pandas given a regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe that I previously transposed. Before the transposition, the numerical column had values float64 and that was expected. However, after the transpose, the float values turned into strings. I tried to convert the dataframe using the .as_type('float') but it got raised with an exception because some columns had values like '4.32 6.50' in the same cell.

I tried using a regex but when I get it to work in only returns something like:

False
False
False
...
False
False

my dataframe looks like this:

```py
q1       q2   q3   q4
4.22     4.11 3.89 4.11
5        2.36 3.68 4.23
1.2 4.63 4.28 5.67 4.87
```

There are over 1000 rows, and there are multiple problematic rows in the dataframe. I don't know what they are. Therefore, manually removing it won't be an option

I tried the following code

```
final = final[~final['q1'].str.contains("\d+\.\d\s\d+\.\d", na = False)]
```

But, the problematic row is still there.

The final result looks like this

```py
q1 q2 q3 q4
```

All the rows went gone. Not all of them are problematic

Comment: Why is your final result just the column names? You want to drop all the rows which have two values in one cell?

Comment: that's what happened when I executed the code right above. I'm not really sure why. And yes, the only thing I want is to drop those columns that have 2 values in a cell

Comment: Try final = final[~final['q1'].str.contains('\.{1}', na = False)]

Comment: What if all rows have whole numbers? @GustavoGradvohl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close with your regex, some small problems though.

---

#### Method 1, cleaning up in specific column

If you know which column is giving the problem, we can use `str.contains` on a specific column:

```
m = ~df['q1'].str.contains('\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+')
df[m]
```

**Output**

```
     q1    q2    q3    q4
0  4.22  4.11  3.89  4.11
1     5  2.36  3.68  4.23
```

---

#### Method 2, searching all columns

If you are not sure which column is giving the problem. We can use `DataFrame.apply` with `.str.contains` and then drop the rows which have `any` cells with multiple values:

```
m = ~df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+')).any(axis=1)
df[m]
```

**Output**

```
     q1    q2    q3    q4
0  4.22  4.11  3.89  4.11
1     5  2.36  3.68  4.23
```

#### Method 3, remove rows with whitespace (kinda dangerous)

First we remove whitespace on left and right border, than remove rows which have whitespaces in between:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

m = ~df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\s')).any(axis=1)
df[m]
```

**Output**

```
     q1    q2    q3    q4
0  4.22  4.11  3.89  4.11
1     5  2.36  3.68  4.23
```

Comment: I think maybe it is better adding astype(float) at the end ?

Comment: @Erfan Thank you! Method 1 worked like a charm. Something I did notice is that all the conflicting rows will have the issue in the first column. For some reason, the other 2 methods didn't work, particularly the 3rd one. Oh well. I really appreciate your help and effort

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned convert to numeric , we using `to_numeric` all the cell can not convert to numeric will be cast to `NaN` , the we `dropna`

```
df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors ='coerce').dropna()
df
Out[388]: 
     q1    q2    q3    q4
0  4.22  4.11  3.89  4.11
1  5.00  2.36  3.68  4.23
```

Comment: I have tried that one before. All the values in the dataframe turned into a NaN